# How to format a number in Extjs?

Tags: extjs, number-formatting

I am calculating some numbers which I have to use to send them to Data Base and show them in the app.

at first I get a number like this: 1721.0238454113.

after some calculations I got a number like this: 
number = 5426.25154751156

In order to show that number in the app I had to format it like this:

```
Ext.util.Format.number(parseFloat(number),'0,000.00')
```

I get something like this : 5.426,25. Which it´s exactly what I wanted.

Now in another section from the app I need to get that number for something else but I need it how it was shown at first, I mean, like this: 5426.25154751156

How can I format the number from 5.426,25 to 5426.25154751156 with all its decimal numbers ?.

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code `Ext.util.Format.number(parseFloat(number),'0,000.00')` transforms your int/float into a string, so you can't transform that string into a float again with all its prior decimal numbers.

My first suggestion's to use a renderer or a renderData if you can (you didn't say what kind of component you are using), so you don't alter the raw value of the number and you can get it later, check out this brief example:

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        var number = 5426.25154751156;
        Ext.create('Ext.Component', {
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            renderTpl: [
                '<h1 id="{id}-title" data-ref="title">{title}</h1>',
                '<p>{msg}</p>',
            ],
            renderData: {
                title: "Formated Number",
                msg: Ext.util.Format.number(parseFloat(number), '0,000.00')
            },
            childEls: ["title"]

        });
        Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
            text: 'Get raw value',
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            listeners: {
                afterrender: function (cmp) {
                    cmp.setHandler(function(){
                        console.log("number",number)
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2s2b)

If your component doesn't have a renderer function then maybe you should use another variable to store the formatted value, so again, you can get the raw value later.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am trying to test your fiddle but it seems there is something wrong with it. When I am clicking the Get Raw Value button, it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Open the console in your browser (F12 in chrome and firefox) and you'll see the value